# Relationship between group $C^\ast$-algebras $C^\ast(G)$ and graph $C^\ast$-algebras $C^\ast(E)$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $E=E(G,S)$ be the graph defined by a group $G$ and a subset $S$ of $G$. What is relationship between group $C^\ast$-algebras $C^\ast(G)$ and graph $C^\ast$-algebras $C^\ast(E)$?

Answer (score 8):

In general, the universal group $C^*$-algebra $C^*(G)$ and the graph algebra $C^*(E)$ of its Cayley graph with respect to a generating set may be very different. For example, let's consider a finite group $G$. If $S$ is a generating set, $E$ is strongly connected. If $G$ is not a cyclic group, then the adjacency matrix for $E$ is not a permutation matrix. In this case, $C^*(G)$ is isomorphic to the group algebra, but $C^*(E)$ is purely infinite.

I think the relationship you might be looking for is the relationship between $G$ and $C^*(E)$. Since $G$ acts on $E$, by the universal property of $C^*(E)$, we have that $G$ acts on $C^*(E)$. Kumjian and Pask (http://www.uow.edu.au/~dpask/index_files/papers/codgaga.pdf) showed that the reduced crossed product $C^*(E)\rtimes_\lambda G$ is isomorphic to $C^*(E/G)\otimes \mathcal{K}(\ell^2(G))$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Dave Penneys :So Tanks for guide me,I have an another question? What is the ideal  structure of group $C^*$ algebras? Dose there exist any books or article in the filed ?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming E is the Cayley  digraph, not very much. Take the Cayley digraph of a finite non-cyclic group with respect to a set of generators. The graph C*-algebra is an infinite dimensional simple C*-algebra and the group algebra is finite dimensional and not simple.

Comment: I'm sorry @Benjamin, it seems you answered while I was typing my answer.

Comment: It happens.  You have more details.

Comment: Dear Prof. Benjamin Steinberg :So Tanks for guide me,I have an another question? What is the ideal structure of group $C^*$ algebras? Dose there exist any books or article in the filed ?

Comment: I'm not an expert in group C*-algebras.  It depends a lot if you want the universal C*-algebra or the reduced one.  For the reduced one it is not so easy to see when it is simple. The universal one has lots of ideals usually.